# Chrome local overrides started to ignore files with version at the end (same issue with Brave, Edge)

Tags: css, google-chrome-devtools, microsoft-edge, devtools

I've been using Chrome local overrides for a while now, but now I've noticed that chrome started to ignore all my CSS files that have a version after the .css

For example

```
main-common.css%3fv=21.1.0.29512
```

doesn't work

but

```
main-common.css
```

does

This seems something new that had to happen in the last two weeks. And it's just on my primary device.

Does anyone have any ideas what could the reason be and / or how to fix it.

Comment: I agree with the answer below. I can reproduce the issue. It's an issue of chromium, you can also report the issue in that issue tracker and wait for the new chromium update to fix the issue.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that it is a problem in the update of chrome (the problem is in all browsers based on chromium) https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1308257&q=devtools%20override&can=2